# could not authenticate with the specified node - ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, selenium-webdriver, nest

Using nest client 7.2.1 to connect to elastic db internal loadbalancer in azure.

Exception: Failed to create DB Index for Alarm Event.Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (401) low level call on HEAD: / # Audit trail of this API call: - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://192.168.0.4:9200/ Exception: PipelineException Took: 00:00:00.0506796 # OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration.. Call: Status code 401 from: HEAD / ---> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration. at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.ThrowBadAuthPipelineExceptionWhenNeeded(IApiCallDetails details, IElasticsearchResponse response) at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TResponse](RequestData requestData) at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- # Audit exception in step 1 BadResponse: Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration. at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.ThrowBadAuthPipelineExceptionWhenNeeded(IApiCallDetails details, IElasticsearchResponse response) at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TResponse](RequestData requestData) at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters) # Request:  # Response:  Unsuccessful (401) low level call on PUT: /asx-sleepquality # Audit trail of this API call: - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://192.168.0.4:9200/ Exception: PipelineException Took: 00:00:00.4294201 # OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration.. Call: Status code 401 from: PUT /asx-sleepquality. ServerError: Type: security_exception Reason: "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/asx-sleepquality]" ---> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration. at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.ThrowBadAuthPipelineExceptionWhenNeeded(IApiCallDetails details, IElasticsearchResponse response) at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TResponse](RequestData requestData) at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- # Audit exception in step 1 BadResponse: Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration. at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.ThrowBadAuthPipelineExceptionWhenNeeded(IApiCallDetails details, IElasticsearchResponse response) at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TResponse](RequestData requestData) at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters) # Request:  # Response:

```
 const string Url = "http://192.168.0.4:9200"; 
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(Url));
            ElasticSearchClient = new ElasticClient(settings);

            var indexes = GetAsxIndexes();

            var response = ElasticSearchClient.Ping().DebugInformation;
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code fix my issue

```
//Reading the configuration from appsettings.json
var elasticConfig = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("ElasticSearch");

// 1. Register NEST ElasticClient
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(elasticConfig["Uri"]))
                    .BasicAuthentication(elasticConfig["UserName"], elasticConfig["Password"])
                    .DefaultIndex(elasticConfig["DefaultIndex"]);

settings.PrettyJson();

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to make a request to an Elasticsearch cluster that has security enabled, based on the error message

> Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration.. Call: Status code 401 from: HEAD /

You need to supply the authentication credentials in the `ConnectionSettings` for the client to use

```cs
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://192.168.0.4:9200"));

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    // configure the client with authentication credentials
    .BasicAuthentication("user", "password");


var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had Error 401 when I enabled Fine-grained access control. Signing the request using AwsSigV4HttpConnection worked for me.
Reference: https://opensearch.org/blog/aws-sigv4-support-for-clients/

```
using OpenSearch.Client;
using OpenSearch.Net.Auth.AwsSigV4;

namespace Application
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var endpoint = new Uri("https://search-xxx.region.es.amazonaws.com");
            var connection = new AwsSigV4HttpConnection();
            var config = new ConnectionSettings(endpoint, connection);
            var client = new OpenSearchClient(config);

            Console.WriteLine($"{client.RootNodeInfo().Version.Distribution}: {client.RootNodeInfo().Version.Number}");
        }
    }
}
```